# Batch file recognition

Tags: batch-file, filesystems

I've got an interesting case playing around with a batch file, which does the following things:

1. Move a jar to a directory
2. Adds all the jars in the directory to a string (for a classpath)
3. Runs the jar

The problem I'm getting is that it doesn't find the new jars while building the string, but it finds existing jars, so if I run it twice it's fine.

To detect the jars, I'm using this:

```
set cp=

for %%a in ("jars/*.jar") do call :concat jars/%%a

:concat

set cp=%cp%;%1
```

If anyone has an explanation or a solution, I'd like to hear it!

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your problem using the provided code. Specifically, the `%cp%` variable is set to exactly what it's supposed to be.

Comment: probably you need `exit /b 0` before `:concat` line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - the copy was from across the network, so it took time. when I add `timeout 4 > NUL` or something similar, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

See !var! vs %var%

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.


.
--
```

Comment: where would you suggest I'd use it? I've tried this: `for %%a in (!lib_loc!) do call :concat jars/%%a`, but it didn't work

Comment: @orirab - it would be in `:concat`. `set cp=!cp!;%1`

Comment: @SomethingDark - didn't work. Also, the flaw doesn't seem to be in the :concat itself, rather in how many times it is called and with what  arguments

Answer (score 0):

```
set "cp="

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in ("jars/*.jar") do set "cp=!cp!;"%%~a""
endlocal &&(
   set "cp=%cp%"
)
echo %cp%
```